# .stp file uploaded to solution section in SPS2013, cant be activated

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, solution

I`ve uploaded .stp files, uploaded to solution section in SPS2013.

However I can't activate .stp from solution section in Site Settings.

Please suggest how to activate .stp file, so that I can create new SPS 2013 app and link already created list (part of .stp)

Comment: is it from different sharepoint version?

Comment: No same version, Sharepoint 2013. Infact List developed on same Sharepoint Farm and within the same site collection. Difference is its developed on a subsite and expectation to allow to create new SPS2013 app on the relevant Parent site

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: No error, i cant see the list while creating sps2013 apps.
My issue: How to activate the .stp file, so it allows to create sps2013 app using the list developed. As of now even though the .stp files are present under Stie Settings - WEb galleries - Templates and in Activate stage. Still I dont get the option to add the list through add apps?